# Filed 2019 taxes in 2022. Which year to claim state income tax refund?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I am catching up with my taxes. I just filed my 2019 Federal and State taxes. I'm now working on 2020.

I had a State refund due for 2019. I applied it, in full, to my 2020 estimated State taxes.

If I had asked for the 2019 refund to be sent to me via check, I would be receiving it soon (in 2022). I would be provided a 1099-G for 2022. Then I would claim that State tax refund on my 2022 taxes (the year I received the check).

But, since I am simply carrying it over to the 2020 tax year (and never actually receiving the money), perhaps I should claim it on the 2020 Federal tax forms...

Should the state refund be claimed on my 2020 or 2022 taxes?

Comment: Did you itemize your deductions (Schedule A) on your 2019 Federal return?

Comment: Why do you think it matters which account the refund gets deposited to?

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica Good call! I didn't itemize in 2019, so it isn't taxable regardless of when I receive it :) In hopes of answering the question for future money.se viewers, I called the IRS, who said it was dependent on which year the state decided to create a 1099-G. I'm assuming it'll be 2022, but I'll call the state and post the answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm back with an answer. I received a 1099-G from Oregon for the 2022 tax year.

In summary, I filed my 2019 and 2020 taxes in 2022. There was an overpayment in TY 2019, which I requested (when filing in 2022) to be applied to future estimated taxes. Although this was applied to TY 2020, it was considered income in 2022.

Ironically, as BenMiller said in the comments, it wasn't taxable income anyway... :)